# Position <b> tag based on mouse position with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="controller">
    <a href="#about" class="arrows" id="aboutarrow">
        <b id="aboutarrow">About</b>
    </a>
    <span class="arrows" id="middle"></span>
    <a href="#members" class="arrows" id="membersarrow">
        <b id="membersarrow">Members</b>
    </a>
    <a href="#servers" class="arrows" id="downarrow"></a>
    <a href="#servers" class="arrows" id="serversarrow">
        <b id="serversarrow">Servers</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

and I want the content of `<b>` tag to be positioned based on the position of the mouse, but I only want the content to be displayed when the mouse rolls over the content of `<a>`, which is a 50 x 50 px block.

Any ideas on how to do this? I hope I've given enough information.

Comment: So you want to place the elements where the mouse pointer is, but only when the mouse rolls over the elements, makes perfect sense ?

Comment: Have you tried using a :hover style for this? At a glance it seems like intervening in the dom with JQuery is really a lot more firepower than you need to throw at this. For example: http://downloads.sixrevisions.com/css-tooltips/index.html which is the demo page for this article: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

Comment: @j_mcnally a bold text tag...

Comment: @adeneo: Pretty much. I'm shooting for a popup-text-bubble-like effect.

Comment: @abathur: Just using a hover style won't quite do the trick...

Comment: if you want it to pop up then you will have to use jquery as the pseudo class in css will not dynamically show and hide the bubble element that he wants to toggle. the pseudo class would only be able to modify the original element that was being hovered over

Comment: You have duplicate `id`s, that is not valid HTML.  Element `id`s must be unique within a document.

Comment: See my edit per links with examples of existing hover popops...

Comment: Popups with CSS is doable, just place the popup inside the hovered element, and hide / show ?

Comment: that's still not a pure css solution. show/hide implies javascript. and yes, your html is all over the place. You're currently showing your a tags to have text but the text is the b tags that you want to show/hide depending on hover. but if you hide them there wont be a visible link at all. what you want to show/hide must be different from the actual text that shows up as the link

Comment: I would be happy to use CSS, but I want a fade effect, and I want the tooltip to move with the mouse. If I can do both of those with CSS, please tell me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With CSS3 :** <kbd>**[CSS3 LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/obagel/3/edit)**</kbd>  (will not follow the mouse ...but hey! )

---

**With jQuery :**

- You can track for your `a` elements that have a `b` inside using `.has()`
- than you just prepare in your CSS an `#tooltip` element and append it with jQuery to DOM
- Than tracking `mouseenter` , `mouseleave`, and `mousemove` you do the apperances and movements of your tooltip

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/obagel/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

    $('body').prepend('<div id="tooltip" />');
    $tool = $('#tooltip');
    var toolW = $tool.outerWidth(true) / 2; // w/2 to make it always horiz. centered

    $('.controller a').has('b').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){

      var opac = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 1 : 0 ;
      var text = $('b', this).text();
      $tool.text(text).stop().fadeTo(300,opac, function(){
          if(opac===0)$tool.hide(); // if mouseleave make sure to hide tooltip
      });

    }).on('mousemove', function( e ){

       var mPos = {X: e.clientX, Y:e.clientY};
       $tool.css({left: mPos.X-toolW, top: mPos.Y+15});

    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.controller a b {      
  display:none;      
}

#tooltip{
  z-index:1000;
  width:180px;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px #666;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [jQuery UI Tooltips](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for example, an custom it as you want, the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) allows you to do almost everything, like [effects](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-animation) and [mouse tracking](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking).

It's really easy to use :

Set a title on your attribute :

```
<a href="#about" class="arrows" id="aboutarrow" title="about">
    <b id="aboutarrow">About</b>
</a>
```

And than throw the tooltip event :

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      track: true
    });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/9c9a7/) and try some things !

Comment: This looks like it will work, let me try it out and I'll be back!

Comment: Customize it as you want, you have a large choice of effects ! See the related links, good luck !